# How to sort by count and retain unique items in value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, of the form

```
col1    col2

k1      'a'
k2      'b'
k1      'a'
k1      'c'
k2      'c'
k1      'b' 
k1      'b'
k2      'c'
k1      'b'
```

I want the output to be

```
k1    ['b', 'a', 'c']
k2    ['c', 'b']
```

So the unique set of entries, sorted by the number of times each entry  occurs (in descending order). In the above example, 'b' is associated with k1 thrice, 'a' twice, and 'c' once.

How do I go about doing this?

```
groupBy($"col1").count()
```

only looks at the number of times the entries in `col1` occur, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. for each key and column value, calculate the count
2. for each key, calculate a list with all related column values and their counts
3. use udf to sort the list and drop the counts

Like that (in Scala):

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row}

val sort_by_count_udf = udf {
  arr: mutable.WrappedArray[Row] =>
    arr.map {
      case Row(count: Long, col2: String) => (count, col2)
    }.sortBy(-_._1).map { case (count, col2) => col2 }
}

val df = List(("k1", "a"), 
  ("k1", "a"), ("k1", "c"), ("k1", "b"), 
  ("k2", "b"), ("k2", "c"), ("k2", "c"), 
  ("k1", "b"), ("k1", "b"))
  .toDF("col1", "col2")

val grouped = df
  .groupBy("col1", "col2")
  .count()
  .groupBy("col1")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("count", "col2")).as("list"))

grouped.withColumn("list_ordered", sort_by_count_udf(col("list"))).show
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (not so pretty solution) using only in-built functions :

```scala
df.groupBy($"col1" , $"col2")
  .agg(count($"col2").alias("cnt") )
  .groupBy($"col1")
  .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct(-$"cnt", $"col2"))).as("list"))
  .withColumn("x" , $"list".getItem("col2") )
  .show(false)
```

Since `sort_array` sorts the elements in ascending order according to their natural ordering `-$"cnt"` helps us in getting the elements sorted in descending order based on their count. `getItem` is used to get the value of `col2` from the struct.

Output:

```scala
+----+------------------------+---------+
|col1|list                    |x        |
+----+------------------------+---------+
|k2  |[[-2,c], [-1,b]]        |[c, b]   |
|k1  |[[-3,b], [-2,a], [-1,c]]|[b, a, c]|
+----+------------------------+---------+
```